# Make a Variable Buffer-Local within a Let-Binding

Tags: buffer-local, let-binding

[12.11.2 Creating and Deleting Buffer-Local Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#index-make_002dlocal_002dvariable):

> Making a variable *buffer-local* within a `let`-binding for that variable does not work reliably, **unless the buffer in which you do this is not current either on *entry to* or *exit from* the `let`**.

So I test an example (in which the buffer is not current either on *entry to* or *exit from* the `let`) in the `*scratch*` buffer:

```lisp
(setq number 0)

(with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
  (let (number)
    (with-current-buffer "*scratch*"
      (make-local-variable 'number)
      (setq number 1))))

number
;; ==> 0
;; Still, it returns the default value.
```

It seems that I did not understand what the *manual* said correctly.

I wonder what the *manual* mean by "work reliably", 
can anyone give me an example that meets the conditions following "unless" and an opposite example that cannot "work reliably"?

---

Then the *manual* continued:

> This is because **`let` does not distinguish between different kinds of bindings**; it knows only which variable the binding was made for.

But according to another example in [12.11.1 Introduction to Buffer-Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html):

```lisp
(setq foo 'g)

(set-buffer "a")
(make-local-variable 'foo)
(setq foo 'a)

(let ((foo 'temp))
  (set-buffer "b")
  foo)
;; ==> g
```

`let` seems to distinguish ...

---

I know that making a variable *buffer-local* within a `let`-binding may not be a good coding convention, but since the *manual* mentioned it, I just want to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works well.
After execution of the code the value of `foo` is 1 in all buffers except buffer `*test2*`, there the value is 3.
This is expected since in buffer `*test2*` the buffer-local value of `foo` was changed.

```el
(unintern 'foo)
(defvar foo)
(setq foo 1)

(list
 (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test1*")
   (let ((foo 2))
     (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test2*")
       (make-variable-buffer-local 'foo)
       (setq foo 3)
       )
     foo
     )
   )
 (with-current-buffer "*test1*"
   foo)
 (with-current-buffer "*test2*"
   foo)
 foo
 )
;; => (2 1 3 1)
```

In the following example the local let-binding of `foo` leaks out of the `let` form.
In buffer `*test1*` the variable `foo` is locally let-bound and set to 3 within the let-body.
Outside the let-body it should have back its old value 1 in buffer `*test1*` but it is still has the value 3.

```el
(unintern 'foo)
(defvar foo)
(setq foo 1)

(list
 (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test1*")
   (let ((foo 2))
     (make-variable-buffer-local 'foo)
     (setq foo 3)
     foo)
   )

 (with-current-buffer "*test1*"
   foo)
 (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test2*")
   foo)
 )
;; => (3 3 1)
```

An important aspect mentioned in [Drew's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76355/make-a-variable-buffer-local-within-a-let-binding/76357?noredirect=1#comment126226_76357):
Let-binding is not buffer local if the locally bound variable is not already declared as buffer-local.
Example:

```el
(unintern 'foo)
(defvar foo 0)

(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test1*")
  (let ((foo 1))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test2*")
      foo)))
```

But, if a variable is already declared as buffer-local a let-binding of this variable is also buffer-local:

```el
(unintern 'foo)
(defvar-local foo 0)

(defvar ans)
(setq ans nil)

(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test1*")
  (setq foo 1)
  (let ((foo 2))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test2*")
      (push foo ans)
      )
    (push foo ans)
    )
  (push foo ans)
  )
(nreverse ans)
;; => (0 2 1)
```

Comment: Why are the results different if I remove the forms `(defvar foo)`?

Comment: @Shynur: If you remove the defvars then foo is bound lexically, assuming `lexical-binding` is non-`nil`.

Comment: This part of the doc of `make-variable-buffer-local` might be relevant here: 
"Note that binding the variable with `let', or setting it while a `let'-style binding made in this buffer is in effect, does not make the variable buffer-local."

Comment: @Drew You mentioned that let-binding does not make variables buffer-local. Right you  are. This would destroy one important use-case of let-bindings: The transfer of values of buffer-local variables from one buffer to another. Org-mode uses this for the duplication of org-buffers when exporting. The buffer modifications through code block execution during export can easily be dismissed through killing the duplicated buffer.

Comment: @Shynur It is good praxis to always declare global variables of packages as special. One often needs to let-bind them in functions to avoid strange effects through customization or to achieve some special behavior.

Comment: @Drew I added an example that shows that a let-binding of a buffer-local variable is also buffer-local.

Comment: Good question; good answer.

Comment: @Drew: “@Shynur: If you remove the defvars then foo is bound lexically, assuming `lexical-binding` is non-`nil`.” --- Surely that's a standard answer, thanks. But actually, the point of my confusion was a little weird at that time. You can see my another [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76405/make-local-variable-behaves-differently-depending-on-whether-variable-is-speci#comment126348_76407).  (This comment is to clarify my last comment.)