# `make-local-variable` Behaves Differently depending on Whether Variable is Special

Tags: buffer-local, let-binding, lexical-scoping, dynamic-scoping

Two examples (both are in the `*scratch*` buffer and under *lexical scoping rule*):

1. _

   ```lisp
   (setq xx :default)

   (let ((xx :let))
     (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "tmp")
       (make-local-variable 'xx)
       ;; set the value of xx, buffer-locally
       (setq xx :tmp)) ; exit from "tmp"
     xx) ; ==> :tmp
   ;; I think that: after exiting from "tmp",
   ;; xx would restore its previous value
   ;; bound by `let`.
   ;; But in fact, it didn't evaluate to :let.

   (with-current-buffer "tmp"
     xx) ; ==> :default
   ;; It seems that even though `let`-binding was
   ;; created in "*scratch*", it removed the 
   ;; binding of the buffer-local variable
   ;; in the buffer "tmp" so that this form didn't
   ;; evaluate to :tmp.
   ```
2. _

   ```lisp
   (defvar yy :default)

   (let ((yy :let))
     (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "tmp")
       (make-local-variable 'yy)
       (setq yy :tmp))
     yy) ; ==> :let
   ;; yy restored its value created by `let`-bing
   ;; after switching back to the original buffer.
   ;; This is intuitive.

   (with-current-buffer "tmp"
     yy) ; ==> :tmp
   ;; `let`-binding didn't remove the binding created
   ;; by (setq yy :tmp).
   ;; It behaved differently from the previous example.
   ```

These comments show my two kinds of understanding, neither is self-consistent.  And they are contradictory to each other.

Why are the results different for these two examples?  
example-1: `:tmp` `:default`
example-2: `:let` `:tmp`

Is there any section, in the [*manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html), explaining the above behaviors?  
I did not find it.

Comment: I know what lexical-binding and dynamic-binding are, but when encountering “buffer-local”, I get confused.

Comment: Somewhat a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27581 except for the focus on buffer-local-ness.

Comment: It's probably worth keeping in mind that GNU Emacs has only supported lexical binding since version 24, released a little over a decade ago, and that there's 25+ years of only-dynamic-binding preceding that; so if you feel the documentation could be doing a better job of covering certain aspects which differ between the two, it's extremely possible that the documentation in question was mostly written before lexical binding was a thing.  Documentation improvements can be suggested via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @phils: This question had been bothering me for several days.  One of my classmates is also reading this *manual*, and if he gets confused when encountering this question as well, it will be time for me to report a request for Documentation Improvement. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables with dynamic scope can have global and buffer-local values, which are associated with the canonical symbol for the variable.

The global vs buffer-local concepts are irrelevant to lexically-scoped variables, which have "indefinite extent" within the lexical scope of the code in question, and (crucially) are *not* tied to the symbol of the same name.

As `(make-local-variable 'xx)` acts on the *symbol* `xx`, it has no bearing on any lexical variable `xx` in that code. (The same comment applies to any function which accesses a variable via a symbol argument.)

It *will* still cause a dynamically-scoped variable of that name to be buffer-local to the temp buffer, but the `(setq xx :tmp)` is setting the lexical variable.  If you were to `(set 'xx :tmp)` OTOH, you'd be setting the dynamic buffer-local variable via the symbol.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Lexical Binding` is the node to read.

Comment: ***Thanks a lot!*** My original thought was that: Since `make-local-variable` is a *built-in* function, I thought it would be able to access *lexical binding*s just like `let` and `setq`, even though its argument is *symbol*-type.